# Help with this Validation Rule

Tags: validation, permissions, validation-rule

I have these particular VR and I needed to open new question because has a specific problems.

There are both (in Account object):

1. Check that a field is not empty in an specific State:

> ```
> AND(
>
> ISPICKVAL(Status__c , "Incubator"),
>
> ISBLANK(Field01__c))
> ```

2. Check that user has special permissions:

> ```
> AND(!$Setup.Bypass__c.ValidationRule__c,
>
> !$Permission.IntegrationPermissions,
>
> $User.Username != $Label.PERMISSION_USER)
> ```

So, I would like to have both VR in just one, checking that IF ONE OF THESE TWO CASES happens. Is like:

OR( VALIDATION RULE 1, VALIDATION RULE 2)

I tried but I had sintax mistakes. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally be using two validation rules for these two apparently separate scenarios. That said, if you still insist, just add an OR between them:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c , "Incubator"),
    ISBLANK(Field01__c)
)
||
AND(
    !$Setup.Bypass__c.ValidationRule__c,
    !$Permission.IntegrationPermissions,
    $User.Username != $Label.PERMISSION_USER
)
```

Or, use OR:

```
OR(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Status__c , "Incubator"),
        ISBLANK(Field01__c)
    ),
    AND(
        !$Setup.Bypass__c.ValidationRule__c,
        !$Permission.IntegrationPermissions,
        $User.Username != $Label.PERMISSION_USER
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

OR(
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Status__c , "Incubator"),
ISBLANK(Field01__c)
),
AND(
!$Setup.Bypass__c.ValidationRule__c,
!$Permission.IntegrationPermissions,
$User.Username != $Label.PERMISSION_USER
)
)